# React : initial state value in html snippet

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './App.css'

let initialState = [{
    type: 'INCREMENT',
    payload: {
        name: "Andrew",
        lastName: 'Radkevich'
    }
}];

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT' :
            return action.payload;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return action.payload;
        default :
            return state
    }
};


let store = createStore(reducer);

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(store.getState().name,'name')
        return <ChildContainer
            value={`${store.getState().name} ${store.getState().lastName}`}
            onClickIncrement={
                () => {
                    store.dispatch({
                        type: 'INCREMENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: "Andrew",
                            lastName: 'Radkevich'
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            onClickDecrement={
                () => {
                    store.dispatch({
                        type: 'DECREMENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: "Igor",
                            lastName: 'Radkevich'
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        />
    }
}


class ChildContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
       // this part of code here 
            <h1 id={'id'}>{this.props.value}</h1>
            <button onClick={this.props.onClickIncrement}>+</button>
            <button onClick={this.props.onClickDecrement}>-</button>
        </div>
    }
}
const render = () => {
    document.getElementById('id').innerText = `${store.getState().name} ${store.getState().lastName}`;
};
store.subscribe(render);
export default App
```

Hi, there ) I have a question about how to load initial state before page is loaded?

{this.props.value} - in this part of the code ( I've added a comment in the snippet above), I want to get value when the page is loaded, but I get undefined ( see below). Why has this happened? If you can explain me also

[image]

Comment: use constructor

Comment: give me an example please how can I solve it if you can

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
....
return <ChildContainer value={`${store.getState().payload[0].name} ${store.getState().payload[0].lastName}`}
...
```

Should fix.

The way you are saving your state is really weird. Also, your code structure is not the best. I advise you to take a small react/redux beginner course/tutorial like [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-redux-tutorial-beginners/).

Comment: thanks for an answer ) but it isn't working .. I've got **(TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined **....
it is only for studying ) I only want to understand how does the state work )

Comment: try value={`${store.getState()[0].payload.name} ${store.getState()[0].payload.lastName}`}, forgot you initialized your state as an array.